# Transposing spark dataframe based on a subcolumn

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe which looks like this:

```
root
|-- 0000154d-7585-5eb283ff985c: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- collaborative_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- curated_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- discovery_score: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- original_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- recipe_id: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|-- 00005426-2675-68085cd359c7: struct (nullable = true)
|    |-- collaborative_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- content_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- curated_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- discovery_score: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- original_rank: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
|    |-- recipe_id: array (nullable = true)
|    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Each column is a user id, e.g. `0000154d-7585-5eb283ff985c`, and each row is made up of 15 000 users (they come from json files that each contain 15 000 users).

I want to transpose it such that each user id is a row, and each sub-column `collaborative_rank, content_rank, curated_rank, discovery_score, original_rank and recipe_id` is a column with the array being the value. I'm new to spark is there any painless way to do this?

**Edit:**

For reference, an input .json file I'm reading from looks like this:

```
{"0000154d-7585-4096-a71a-5eb283ff985c": {"recipe_id": [1, 2, 3], "collaborative_rank": [1, 2, 3], "curated_rank": [1, 2, 3], "discovery_score": [1]}, "00005426-2675-4940-8394-e8085cd359c7": {"recipe_id": [] ... }
```

etc.

Comment: Post your question and expected answer in a table structure so that it gives more clarity

Comment: What do you mean? How should I reformat it?

Comment: could you put a input single row json element atleast. so that we can extract the data and give it to you as in rows & columns as expected?

Comment: I added an example of what the json file looks like. Is that what you meant?

Comment: thanks @sashsash96, let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to convert it to rdd and perform UDF, you can consider stacking the dataframe.

```
df = spark.read.json(r'C:\stackoverflow\samples\inp.json')

stack_characteristics = str(len(df.columns))+','+','.join([f"'{v}',`{v}`" for v in df.columns])

df.select(expr(f'''stack({stack_characteristics})''').alias('userId','vals')).\
   select('userId', 'vals.*').show()

+--------------------+------------------+------------+---------------+---------+
|              userId|collaborative_rank|curated_rank|discovery_score|recipe_id|
+--------------------+------------------+------------+---------------+---------+
|0000154d-7585-409...|         [1, 2, 3]|   [1, 2, 3]|            [1]|[1, 2, 3]|
|00005426-2675-494...|         [1, 2, 3]|   [1, 2, 3]|            [1]|[1, 2, 3]|
+--------------------+------------------+------------+---------------+---------+
```

Comment: I'm getting this error with this:
```NameError: name 'expr' is not defined```

Comment: Hope this helps! 
`from pyspark.sql.functions import expr`

Comment: `>>> stack_characteristics = str(len(df.columns))+','+','.join([f"'{v}',`{v}`" for v in df.columns])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    stack_characteristics = str(len(df.columns))+','+','.join([f"'{v}',`{v}`" for v in df.columns])
                                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
in python 2.7.5 pyspark 2.2.0

Comment: Python 2.7 doesn't supports f strings instead use .format

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this below code may solve your problem.
input json considered,

```
{"0000154d-7585-4096-a71a-5eb283ff985c": {"recipe_id": [1, 2, 3], "collaborative_rank": [1, 2, 3], "curated_rank": [1, 2, 3], "discovery_score": [1] }}
```

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

#read an input data
df=spark.read.json("/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/input.json")


#method to extract keys to columns
def extract_json(row):
    out_array = []
    data_dict = row.asDict()
    for k in data_dict.keys():
            out_array.append(Row(k, data_dict[k][0], data_dict[k][1],data_dict[k][2],data_dict[k][3]))
    return Row(*out_array)


#flatmap columns and extracting the data
rdd = df.rdd.flatMap(extract_json)

#df creation
df1=spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

df1.selectExpr("_1 as user_id","_2 as recipe_id", "_3 as collaborative_rank", "_4 as curated_rank", "_5 as discovery_score").show(truncate=False)
/*
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+------------+---------------+
|user_id                             |recipe_id|collaborative_rank|curated_rank|discovery_score|
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+------------+---------------+
|0000154d-7585-4096-a71a-5eb283ff985c|[1, 2, 3]|[1, 2, 3]         |[1]         |[1, 2, 3]      |
+------------------------------------+---------+------------------+------------+---------------+

*/
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great when I'm reading 1 json file directly, but I'm reading in a folder of json files, and I get an error on this line ```df1=spark.createDataFrame(rdd)``` Any idea what I can do to fix it?

Comment: ```TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: It seems like it treats each file as a row of the dataframe?

Comment: `df=spark.read.json("/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/*")` can you try with this?!

Comment: It doesn't like that it ends up with the same error. Also I'm reading from an S3 bucket if that makes any difference

Comment: Let me try loading multiple files and get back to you.

Comment: above code is working with mulitple files also, for that please use `df=spark.read.json("/home/sathya/Desktop/stackoverflo/*")` , wildcard * to read all json files within a directory or nested directories

Comment: I did use the wildcard, but it gives the same error. I think the issue is not that it doesn't read all files, but that it reads them in separate rows in the dataframe.